# LookbackAPI: How long to wait for schema changes?

Tags: rally, lookbackapi

We added a new field to our UserStories yesterday.  When I do a query for stories with the LookbackAPI and set fields = true, I see our old custom fields, but not the new one we just added.

How long typically does one have to wait to see new schema changes appear in the lookback API?

Of course, I cannot query against this new field which is what I really want to accomplish here.

Comment: We had a problem which caused us to pause the ETL for some subscriptions for a while. Is it updated now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you looking specifically at stories that you've set the field on? Adding a new field won't automatically add that field to all stories in the LBAPI - the new field will only show on those stories that get updated to include a value for the new field.

Comment: Yes that was part of it-- I'm using a boolean field and looking for the transition to true, and I also I had to look for a transition of undefined to true as well as false to true.